# using VC++ 6.0 .obj files in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have .obj files from Visual C++ 6.0 (1998) that I would like to use as-is in Visual Studio 2015 projects to avoid recompiling.
1) Is this possible?
2) If so, how do I do it? 
These are built as single-thread (/ML or /MLd compiler option). VS15 C++ appears to offer only multi-thread models, with Linker library clashes I have not been able to resolve. Even a dirt-simple multi-thread VC++ test function will not link. What am I doing wrong??
It seems to me unlikely that Microsludge would invalidate these earlier formats.

I have tried all VS15 settings and options I can think of and find, including adding VC++ libraries in the Linker and various \NODEFAULTLIB placements. The Linker can recognize the function in the .obj but then throws a variety of undefineds...

If, instead of using the existing .obj, I add the source code to the VS15 project, all is well....

Comment: _"to avoid recompiling"_ Worst reasoning I ever heard. I seriously doubt these would work well.

Comment: If you have the source code there's no good reason to do what you're asking about.

Comment: Agree entirely with @Retired Ninja. The cost of getting it to working state from obj can be very high. Use source since you have it.

Comment: I think that if the object files were build from C++ there's a good chance of problems.  If they were straight C then chances are much better to be able to use them as-is.  However, if you have the source, I'd try rebuilding the libraries using the new toolchain. But then you buy the headaches of getting the old source to build with new tools, which might not be insignificant.

Comment: It seems unlikely to you that Microsoft would change the format of their object files (OBJ) at some point in the past 20 years? Not to me, it doesn't. How are they supposed to support new C++ language features if they never change their object file format?